Expected value of iterated binomial distribution
Let $B(n,p)$ denote the binomial distribution, where $n$ is the number of trials and $p$ is the probability of success for each trial.
I know that the expected value of $X$ for $X \sim B(n,p)$ is $np$.
However, suppose I do the following: Let $X_1$ be drawn from $B(n,p)$ and let $X_2$ be drawn from $B(X_1, p)$.
What is the expected value of $X_2$?
Moreover, what can be said about doing more than one iteration?
That is, the expected value of $X_k$, where $X_k$ is drawn from $B(X_{k-1},p)$ and so on, until $X_1$ is drawn from $B(n,p)$.
I suppose this can be modeled using conditional expectation, but I could not figure out how to do this with respect to the change of the parameter in the distribution.

It is not too difficult if you look for the distribution of $X_2$ (and more generally $X_k$).  Think about $n$ biased coins, each heads with probability $p$.  $X_1$ is the number of coins showing heads after the first flip.  $X_2$ is the number of those $X_1$ coins also showing heads after a second flip, and $X_k$ is the number showing heads $k$ times in $k$ flips.  For an individual coin, what is the probability it shows  heads $k$ times in $k$ flips?


I suppose this can be modeled using conditional expectation, but I could not figure out how to do this with respect to the change of the parameter in the distribution.

Having the distribution of $X_2$ depending on $X_1$ as a parameter, actually means that $X_2$ is conditionally distributed with respect to $X_1$.
$$\begin{align}X_2\mid X_1&\sim\mathcal{Bin}(X_1,p)\\[1ex]\therefore\quad\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1)&=X_1p\end{align}$$
So the total expectation for $X_2$ is easily found, just as you supposed, by the law of total expectation.
$$\begin{align}X_1&\sim\mathcal{Bin}(n,p)\\[1ex]\therefore\quad
\mathsf E(X_2) &= \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1))\\&=\mathsf E(X_1p)\\&= np^2\end{align}$$
Now if $X_3\mid X_2\sim\mathcal{Bin}(X_2, p)$, then you can likewise find the total expectation for $X_3$, and you should then be able to see a clear pattern emerge.
$\blacksquare$

Another way to solve this problem is to consider probability-generating functions, as they characterize the law of a discrete random variable (in fact, the key formula I'm using is also a consequence of the law of total expectation).
Definition: for $X:\Omega\to \mathbb N$ a discrete random variable, we define its probability-generating function $G_X$ as
$$G_X(t)=\mathbb E[t^X]$$
Some useful results:

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $G_{X+Y}=G_X\times G_Y$ ;
If $X\sim \text{Ber}(p)$, $G_X(t)=1-p+pt$ ;
From those two first points, we deduce that if $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$, then $G_X(t)=(1-p+pt)^n$ ;
If $X=\sum_{k=1}^{S}X_k$, where the $X_k$ and $S$ are independent, then $G_X=G_S\circ G_{X_1}$ ;
If $X$ is integrable, then $\mathbb E[X]=\lim_{t\nearrow 1}G(t)$.

With these remarks, we have about everything we need to solve this problem.
Here $X_1\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$, so $G_{X_1}(t)=(1-p+pt)^n$. For $k\geqslant 0$,
$$X_{k+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{X_k}Y_{i,k}$$
where the $Y_{k,i}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli variables of parameter $p$. Then
$$G_{X_{k+1}}=G_{X_k}\circ G_{Y_{1,k}}$$
With an easy recursion, you can show that for $k\geqslant 1$,
$$G_{X_k}(t)=\left(1-p+p\left(p^{k-1}(t-1)+1\right)\right)^n$$
Its derivative is given by
$$\frac{\partial G_{X_k}(t)}{\partial t}=np^k \left(1-p+p\left(p^{k-1}(t-1)+1\right)\right)^{n-1}$$
Taking $t=1$ yields
$$\mathbb E[X_k]=G'(1)=np^k$$
With this technique, you can also express all the factorial moments of $X_k$:
$$\mathbb E\left[X_k(X_k-1)\dots (X_k-j+1)\right]=G^{(k)}(1)=\frac{n!}{(n-j)!}p^{jk}$$
and then, all the moments:
$$\mathbb E\left[X_k^j\right]=\sum_{i=0}^j\left\{\begin{array}{c}j\\i\end{array}\right\}\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}p^{ik}$$
where the $\left\{\begin{array}{c}j\\i\end{array}\right\}$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind.
